# How to fetch the value of a variable from one if condition inside another if condition?

Tags: perl

Here, my code will run for 2 iterations. For 1st iteration, it will directly go to 2nd if condition. There after some operations, it will print the value of $vg_name as "n_vg_f". Till here the code works fine. Now, for 2nd iteration, first the control goes to above if condition. There while calling function _create(), I need to pass the argument -vg_name as the value of $vg_name which we got in first iteration from the below if condition. Please help me find a way to do this.

```
for(my $x=1;$x<=2;$x++) {
    if($x >= 2){
        $linux_host_obj->_create(-vg_name => $vg_name);
    }
    if($x >= 1){
        print("VG Name is:", $vg_name);   #Here I get $vg_name value as "n_vg_f"
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get? Where do you declare `$vg_name`?

Comment: `-vg_name` probably needs to be quoted, like `$linux_host_obj->_create('-vg_name' => $vg_name)`

Comment: @GMB, No, that isn't necessary. `-vg_name` is equivalent to `"-vg_name"`.

Comment: From the question, it's really unclear what you're trying to accomplish, and also what's wrong with the current code.

Answer (score 0):

It's really not clear what you're trying to do here. But if you want to retain the value of `$vg_name` variable between iterations of the loop, then you need to declare the variable outside of the loop.

```
my $vg_name;

for my $i (1 .. 2) { # this loop style is easier to follow
  if ($i == 2) {
    # do stuff with $vg_name
  }
  if ($i == 1) {
    $vg_name = 'something';
  }
  print "Iteration: $i, vg_name: $vg_name\n";
}
```